# In c# how to Start new process, without being a child of the spawning process?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using Process.start(). But in that case it is getting created as a child of the calling process.

Comment: Are you setting the [StartInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) for the `Process` you are attempting to start, or at least calling `Process.start` with the file name?

Comment: I am calling as Process.Start(fullPathtoexe);